# Stripe Multiple Cards Behaviour

Tags: stripe-payments

We know Stripe supports multiple credit cards. One is default_card. I need to know few answers regarding this Stripe multiple cards.

Suppose I want to charge to my client who have 3 credit cards on his Stripe profile.

1) I have charged to my client but charge failed due to insufficient amount of money. In that case can I charge through 2nd or 3rd card automatically?

2) If possible through 2nd or 3rd card, then I have to handle it from my code or Stripe handles it? Meaning is if 1st card is failed then Stripe will automatically check 2nd or 3rd card for sufficient balance or I have to handle it from my code?

3) Is charge is processed through only default_card?

Please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 4):

Stripe will not automatically attempt to charge non-default cards if a charge fails using the default card. You'd have to handle this from your own code.

In order to charge a non-default card, you must use both the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer) parameter (set to the customer's ID) and the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter (set to the card's ID).

See this StackOverflow answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34416413/5307473