# How to add multiple card for a single customer id and transfer money directly using stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**It is possible in stripe payment gateway?**

we will using stripe for payment,firstly i am creating token.

```
$result = Stripe_Token::create(
                    array(
                        "card" => array(
                            "name" => $user['name'],
                            "number" => base64decrypt($user['card_number']),
                            "exp_month" => $user['month'],
                            "exp_year" => $user['year'],
                            "cvc" => base64decrypt($user['cvc_number'])
                        )
                    )
                );
```

after using token create customer save card.

```
 $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                                "card" => $token,
                                "description" => "New customer",
                                "email" => $users->email
                                    )
                    );
```

and after create charge.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
                 array('card' => $token->token,
                                'amount' => $token->amount * 100,
                                'currency' => 'usd',
                                )
            );
```

but i can't find save multiple card in single customer.
please help me.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should never create tokens server-side in production. In order to be eligible for [PCI SAQ A](https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines), you must create the card tokens client-side, using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).

Once you receive the token on your server, you can use it in a few different manners:

- you can use it to directly [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), without using customer objects at all, by passing the token ID (`"tok_..."`) in the `source` parameter. In this case the card information will be "lost" and you'll need to collect the information again and create a new token to charge this card again in the future.
- you can use it to [create a new customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).
- you can use it to [add a card to an existing customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card).

When [creating charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) with customer objects, you need to pass the customer's ID (`"cus_..."`) in the `customer` parameter. If you don't pass a `source` parameter, then the customer's default card will be used. If you want to charge a non-default card, then in addition to the `customer` parameter, you'll also need to pass the card's ID (`"card_..."`) in the `source` parameter.

Cf. [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34416413/5307473).