# No such token error is coming in stripe payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am implementing **stripe payment gateway** in **cakephp** project.

**Below is the code which i have tried :**

```html
  require_once('stripelib/vendor/autoload.php');
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        try {
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                        "amount" => $data['total'] * 100,
                        "currency" => "usd",
                        "card" => $token,
                        "description" => "Charge for Facebook Login code."
            ));
            //  pr($charge);exit;
        }
```

Here problem is merchant is not getting amount and **i got below error** :

> {"error":"No such token:
>   card_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(invalid_request_error)"}

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a card ID (`"card_..."`) rather than a token ID (`"tok_..."`) to create the charge.

See this StackOverflow answer for more information on how to create charges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34416413/5307473