# Stripe Payment: Customer cus_***** does not have a linked card with ID card_*****

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe with Android I can't find what I a doing wrong to get this error :

> Customer cus_xxx does not have a linked source with ID card_yyy
>   com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Customer cus_xxx does not have a linked source with ID card_yyy.

I have already seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415987/stripe-payment-getting-error-as-customer-cus-does-not-have-a-linked-card) that deals with a comparable issue but mine is different.

Here is my workflow :

1.On my app I create a card with this code

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(context, PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
// Stripe API call to get paymentSourceId
stripe.createToken(card, new TokenCallback(){...});
```

This method is an HTTP API request and I get my `paymentSourceId = card_yyy` from the response to this webservice.

2.I get ephemeral key with an HTTP API request to my backend, I extract `paymentSourceCustomerId = cus_xxx` from ephemeral key

3.Finally I try to create a charge with this parameters

```
{
    "amount":2999,
    "currency":"USD",
    "paymentSourceCustomerId":"cus_xxx",
    "paymentSourceId":"card_yyy"
}
```

And then I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass **paymentSourceId** with **paymentSourceCustomerId**, it is required to have that card linked with that customedId.

You have two option to link a card with customer:

1. At the time of customer creation

> ```
> curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
>    -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
>    -d description="Customer for emily.harris@example.com" \
>    -d source=token
> ```

2. Linking card to already created customer

> ```
> curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_D1p9ZtnrPS4XAR/sources \ 
> -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \   
> -d source=token
> ```

For more details:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, my problem was that my card was not linked to my custumer. Thanx a lot